# Table borders aren't being filled

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the following to autofill top and bottom table borders for cells Q2:T200 :

```
Sub autofiller()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Pharmacontacts")

With ws.Range("Q2:T200").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlThin
.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213)
End With
With ws.Range("Q2:T200").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlDouble
.Weight = xlThick
.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213)
End With
End Sub
```

The problem is the table borders aren't being filled. I encountered the same problem with:

```
With Range("Q2:T200").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.color = RGB(91,155,213)
.Weight = xlThin

End With
With Range("Q2:T200").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlDouble
.color = RGB(91,155,213)
.Weight = xlThick
End With
```

Also tried this:

```
With Range("Q2:T200")
    With .Rows(.Rows.Count)
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .Color= RGB(91,155,213)
        End With
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .Color= RGB(91,155,213)
        End With
    End With
End With
```

I've tried other code online that addressed the same objective. None of the code I found online works - but seems to work for everyone else!

Comment: Just to make sure - you get *no* border at all, running that first one?  What if you step through the code, with F8? Still nothing happens?  No errors too?  The first code you give worked for me, I got a top border and double bottom border...hm.

Comment: Hm - Create a new workbook, change the sheet name in your macro to "Sheet1" and run it, see if it works then on the new workbook...  Also, make sure your activeworkbook and worksheet exists (I'm sure you have, but silly oversights certainly happen).  Also, before both `With` statements, add `ws.Range("Q2:T200").Select` and step through - this will make sure that the range you're expecting to border is correct...

Comment: Ok i tried that, it seems to only fill the first row(Q2:T2), but nothing after that. I changed the cell reference to (Q2:Q100) to see if it would work, but still only the first row would fill. Added in `ws.Range("Q2:T200").Select` but still same problem, only the first row is being filled. Forgot to mention that only the top border is being filled for the first row, no bottom border

Comment: Also, you just want row 2 to have a line, and 200 to have a line - no lines in between?  I'm able to get it to put a top line on T2 and a double bottom line at 200.

Comment: I want top/bottom for everything in between Q2:T200. My bad @BruceWayne, I should've specified wanting it filled for every cell in between that range

Comment: Aha! Now I see (and @Davesexcel got it).  Glad to see you got it worked out.  Just for my curiosity, does your first macro just put a line at row 2, and then at row 200, with nothing in between? Or does it straight up not do anything?

Comment: Yeah it did do that, but I never bothered checking row 200 until you mentioned it because I thought it simply wasn't working. Your help was appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to loop through each cell, for example:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    For Each cell In Range("Q2:T200")
        With cell.Borders(xlTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = RGB(91, 155, 213)
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next cell
    For Each cell In Range("Q2:T200")
        With cell.Borders(xlBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlDouble
            .Color = RGB(91, 155, 213)
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: This adds a single top line to row 2, then double lines for each cell all the way to 200. I think OP just needed a top line, and a bottom double line, without in between borders.  Although, I'm curious to know if this works for OP like it does for me/us.  If not, there's something else going on I think...

Comment: @BruceWayne, that's what i wanted. I thought the range input would automatically loop for each cell but I was wrong.

Davesexcel, thanks a lot, this worked!